# Python - Beautiful Soup, how to get first value of tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this tag:

```
<span class="companyName">Actua Corp <acronym title="Central Index Key">CIK</acronym>#: <a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&amp;CIK=0001085621&amp;owner=include&amp;count=40">0001085621 (see all company filings)</a></span>
```

**How would I obtain the value after** `<span class="companyName">`.

Which in this case is Actua Corp.

I'm open to all methods.

Comment: Please post your current code in your question so we know what you need. Otherwise it seems that you are asking us to write a whole program for you, or are you asking about one or two specific lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want `Actua Corp`, you can use `next`

```
r = '<span class="companyName">Actua Corp <acronym title="Central Index Key">CIK</acronym>#: <a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&amp;CIK=0001085621&amp;owner=include&amp;count=40">0001085621 (see all company filings)</a></span>'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

span = soup.find('span', {'class': 'companyName'})
print(span.next)
>>> Actua Corp
```

If you want all of the text within the `span`, you can use `text`

```
print(span.text)
>>> Actua Corp CIK#: 0001085621 (see all company filings)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much. This is best answer, I'll give it after the 5 min time limit